# String to Image for a Picturebox

Tags: vb.net, string, image, arraylist, picturebox

I have an ArrayList, each string of the ArrayList has as an entry the path of an exact image stored into my Resources (ex. Arraylist(0) = "My.Resources.img1").
I want to display some images in Pictureboxes, I thought that this code should do the trick... But there is a conflict, the app runs without errors but not a single image isn't displayed. I also checked the entries, the path are correct...

```
Dim res As Resources.ResourceManager
    res = New Resources.ResourceManager("Picture_Quiz.Resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly)

'AnswersList is the ArraryList that contains the paths'
PictureBoxA.Image = resGetObject(AnswersList(0))

'I tried to use is as a String Variable instead of string from ArrayList (for no reason)'
Dim img As String
img = My.Resources.img1
PictureBoxB.Image = res.GetObject(img)

PictureBoxC.Image = res.GetObject(AnswerList(2))
PictureBoxD.Image = res.GetObject(AnswerList(3))
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Use the `ImageLocation` property.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict and some of the errors will be highlighted for you.  To load by name:  `picBox.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(STRING_IMGNAME), Image)`  But yes, if you just load a list of file names, ImageLocation will work better and you can manage the list without recompiling

Comment: I have to create a new sub to add ImageLocation property, or I can do it into the existing one?

I replaced STRING_IMGNAME with the string, but still it couldn't load the images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered re-writing the code so that you store an array of Enums?

```
 Enum ResourcePics
   Pic1
   Pic2
   Pic3
  End Enum
```

then use a select to convert the Enum to the resource Image

```
Select Case AnswersList(index)
   Case ResourcePics.Pic1
    Return My.Resources.Pic1
   Case ResourcePics.Pic2
    Return My.Resources.Pic2
   Case ResourcePics.Pic3
    Return My.Resources.Pic3
  End Select
```